# Do stellar black hole precess like Earth do?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, precession

The precession of Earth caused by the Sun and Moon pull like when you breathe super hard on a spinning top, what about massive blackhole which is a point in space conserving it's angular momentum? I know millisecond magnetar precess as it points it jet in our direction periodically not sure about black hole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, black holes can precess.

In binary consisting of two black holes, both spins and the orbital angular momentum will precess about the total angular momentum.

In April, LIGO and Virgo announced the first detection of a binary black hole merger where the black hole spins were precessing: [GW190412](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW190412)